# Any Extension in VS code to integrate with Adobe CRX/CQ content

Tags: visual-studio-code, aem

Is there any plugin through which I can integrate Visual Studio Code with Adobe Experience Manager without time-consuming builds, deploys, or lunching heavy CRXDE.

There is plugin in Submime Text 2 , VLT (https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Vlt) , but is it possible in vs code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there isn't. (As of Oct 2017)

If escaping time consuming builds is your goal than you can use gulp  to deploy files to AEM on change. For some time I used a package named gulp-slang. You should try that.

Answer (score 1):

Don't know if you still need one, but I've been working on one for a little while.  Someone linked it above but that was way before it worked.  I've got it published to the Visual Studio Code Marketplace now and it seems stable, but could definitely use more people trying it out.

https://github.com/Yinkai15/vscode-aem-sync

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Yinkai15.aemsync

Answer (score 0):

There is an extension made for Visual Studio Code for AEM:
https://github.com/kumalee/aem-vscode-extension

Comment: Your answer should not be just a simple link.

Answer (score 0):

look at https://github.com/Yinkai15/vscode-aem-sync

A Visual Studio Code extension to sync changes to an AEM (Adobe Experience Manager) server.

Answer (score 0):

When the question was asked, there doesn't appear to be any plugins but for anybody else stumbling upon this question, I found this AEM Sync plugin for VS Code. It's new and but works pretty well.

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Yinkai15.aemsync